# strata() from "sampling" returns an error: arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   1090 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ id            : chr  "INC000000209241" "INC000000218488" "INC000000218982" "INC000000225646" ...
 $ service.type  : chr  "Incident" "Incident" "Incident" "Incident" ...
 $ priority      : chr  "Critical" "Critical" "Critical" "Critical" ...
```

I order the data as follows:

```
data <- data[order(data$priority),]
```

I have been changing priority to factors etc but regardless what I try, when I try running the below:

```
s = strata(data,c("priority"),size=c(0,0,1,5))
```

I always get the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

I tried debugging the function to see whether I could tell why this error is raised (but I couldn't make sense of the code). The error was raised at this stage of executing the strata() function:

```
debug: r = cbind(r, i)
```

Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: You don't provide a reproducible example, so it is hard to help you? also `strata` is from which package, `survival`?

Comment: @agstudy, it's from the "sampling" package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in your trying to set the sample size from some groups equal to zero. Instead, subset your original data before sampling.

Here, we reproduce your problem.

```
library(sampling)
data(swissmunicipalities)
length(table(swissmunicipalities$REG)) # We have seven strata
# [1] 7

# Let's take two from each group
strata(swissmunicipalities, 
       stratanames = c("REG"), 
       size = rep(2, 7), 
       method="srswor")
#      REG ID_unit        Prob Stratum
# 93     4      93 0.011695906       1
# 145    4     145 0.011695906       1
# 2574   1    2574 0.003395586       2
# 2631   1    2631 0.003395586       2
# 826    3     826 0.006230530       3
# 1614   3    1614 0.006230530       3
# 583    2     583 0.002190581       4
# 1017   2    1017 0.002190581       4
# 1297   5    1297 0.004246285       5
# 2535   5    2535 0.004246285       5
# 342    6     342 0.010752688       6
# 347    6     347 0.010752688       6
# 651    7     651 0.008163265       7
# 2471   7    2471 0.008163265       7

# Let's try to drop the first two groups. Oops...
strata(swissmunicipalities, 
       stratanames = c("REG"), 
       size = c(0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
       method="srswor")
# Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
#   arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

Let's subset and try again.

```
swiss2 <- swissmunicipalities[!swissmunicipalities$REG %in% c(1, 2), ]
table(swiss2$REG)
strata(swiss2, 
       stratanames = c("REG"), 
       size = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
       method="srswor")
#      REG ID_unit        Prob Stratum
# 58     4      58 0.011695906       1
# 115    4     115 0.011695906       1
# 432    3     432 0.006230530       2
# 986    3     986 0.006230530       2
# 1007   5    1007 0.004246285       3
# 1150   5    1150 0.004246285       3
# 190    6     190 0.010752688       4
# 497    6     497 0.010752688       4
# 1049   7    1049 0.008163265       5
# 1327   7    1327 0.008163265       5
```

Comment: terrific, thank you very much! I somehow stumbled on this as well but really appreciate you taking the time to clarify this and will use the elegant way of subsetting as suggested by you! thanks again

Comment: (Self-promotion alert): @dreamwalker, you may also want to check out a function I wrote for stratified sampling from a `data.frame`. It's called `stratified` and is available as part of [this package](https://github.com/mrdwab/mrdwabmisc). It will let you use syntax like `stratified(swissmunicipalities, "REG", c(0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2))` without any error, probably because of how the splitting and recombining of the original `data.frame`s take place.