# Adstock Application: Arguments Imply Different Number of Rows

Tags: r, runtime-error, regression

I'm new to R and trying to set up regression runs on data
with an Adstock - like decay incorporated into that data.
A web search revealed an example that I have attempted to adapt 
for my purposes, but I'm having the problem described here 
in this simplified example.  (There may be more problems; 
any comments welcome!)

```
# adstock calc
adstock_Nx_calc <- function(media){
  length <- length(media)
  adstock <- rep(0,length)
  for(i in 2:length){
    adstock[i] <- media[i] + (adstock[i-1]*.7)
  }
}

# Function for creating Nx test sets
create_Nxtest_sets<-function(base_p){

  # 10 weeks of data
  week <- 1:10

  # Base sales of base_p units
  base<-rep(base_p,10)

  # set up NxE parameters
  NxE <- c(24,14,33,19,32,10,5,15,12,1)

  # set up adstock
  adstock <- adstock_Nx_calc(NxE)

  # sales equation
  sales <- base + NxE + adstock

  # set up output data.frame
  output<-data.frame(week, sales, NxE, adstock)
  output  
}

test <- create_Nxtest_sets(base_p=1500)
```

The resulting error is "arguments imply different number of rows: 10, 0"
I've searched both generally and in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439871/error-in-data-framemm-1-surv-t-surv-t-cens-cens-arguments-imply-di) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735411/strata-from-sampling-returns-an-error-arguments-imply-differing-number-of-r), but these don't seem to be related.  I guess the error means that adstock is not calculating and is therefore NULL, but I cannot 
figure out why; any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return adstock from adstock_Nx_calc, like this:

```
adstock_Nx_calc <- function(media){
  length <- length(media)
  adstock <- rep(0,length)
  for(i in 2:length){
    adstock[i] <- media[i] + (adstock[i-1]*.7)
  }
  return(adstock)
}
```

Comment: The example I was following didn't have that, but it does work.  Thanks, much, @Ista, and so quickly!!! My next step is to rework the example as zoo objects since my real project is all done in zoo.  Any comments as to the applicability of this script/solution to zoo?